# Git Hooks: make branch contain specific characters

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks, verification

I'm starting to learn how I can implement hooks into my Git project. I would like it so each team member is required to have their name inserted in the branch name also. This is what I have written so far.

```
local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

valid_branch_regex="^(Taylor|Sean|Ali|Yusuf|Niki|Wiktoria)\/[a-z0-9._-]+$"

message="There is something wrong with the branch name: Branch name must contain your First Name,
 For example: $valid_branch_regex. Please re-commit with the correct changes."

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
  echo "$message"
  exit 1
fi
```

Is it possible to alter this slightly to accept _Ali or -Niki for example.

Sorry im very new to Git!

Answer (score 2):

Start regex with `^[-_]?`.

But this looks like a bad idea. First of all, it's a client-side hook, everyone has to install the hook, and if they forget, the server doesn't validate the branch name. Also, no one cares what branch names people use in their local repository.

You should create a server-side hook (update hook looks suitable) and ideally, read the names from however you authenticate the users and possibly even check if they used their own name. But if you move this script to the server, it's already much better.

Resources:

- [update hook manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update)
- [Intro to hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- [Example](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)

Comment: If your platform doesn't support hooks (for example, GitHub), you can also enforce this in your CI system.